# How to display a list of images fitting the screen in web programming

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

I have just started web programming and I was wondering whether there'd be a solution for my problem.

I have 10 images and I would like to display them according to the screen size. I mean if the browser could just fit 2 images, then I would expect something like:

```
Image1    Image2
Image3    Image4
...       ...
Image9    Image10
```

If the browser could fit more than 2 images, lets say 4, then I would expect something like:

```
Image1    Image2    Image3    Image4
...       ...       ...       ...
Image9    Image10
```

I have stored my images in a json file:

```
{
  "images": [
    {"title": "Image One", "url": "1.jpeg"},
    {"title": "Image Two", "url": "2.jpeg"},
    {"title": "Image Three", "url": "3.jpeg"},
    ...
  ]
}
```

Any tip, suggestion, help, advise would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Downvoters state your reasons! If I would've known the way how to do so, I would not be here~

Comment: You need to be more specific when you ask your questions or else you'll see a lot of down voting.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am totally new to web programming I couldn't be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block` CSS property to achieve this. Here i am going to give some small example.

**HTML**

```
<div class="test"><img src="test.jpg" /></div>
<div class="test"><img src="test.jpg" /></div>
<div class="test"><img src="test.jpg" /></div>
<div class="test"><img src="test.jpg" /></div>
<div class="test"><img src="test.jpg" /></div>
<div class="test"><img src="test.jpg" /></div>
<div class="test"><img src="test.jpg" /></div>
<div class="test"><img src="test.jpg" /></div>
<div class="test"><img src="test.jpg" /></div>
<div class="test"><img src="test.jpg" /></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.test
{
display:inline-block;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rC3YA/1/)

In the above demo, Images will occupy the spaces based on screen width.

Comment: This answer was useful.

Comment: This is a great start. If you find that you want more control over how the images are laid out on the page you can use flexboxes: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is learn responsive design/development.  Please look at something like the bootstrap framework.

http://getbootstrap.com